# How to access the form object on a angular 1.6 / es6 application?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I am working on a app that uses angular 1.6 with es6.
I have a form :

```
<form name="foobar" ng-submit="$ctrl.submitThat()"  novalidate>
```

in the submitThat() function I would like to access the form object and check its validation state, but it does not seems to be available on the $scope object. The $scope object exist, I made sure to pass it as param of the contructor of the controller class, but it has no "foobar" attribute (the form name).

```
class StuffController {
/*@ngInject*/
constructor($translate, StuffService, $log, $interval, $scope) {
    this.$translate = $translate;
    this.StuffService= StuffService;
    this.$log = $log;
    this.$interval = $interval;
    this.$scope = $scope;
    //more unrelated code
}
submitThat(){
   console.log(this.$scope);//outputed object misses the foobar property
    }
}
```

I forgot to add that the app uses webpack.

Comment: create all `ng-model` in form using a same object

Comment: I rechecked and they are on the same object. This object is attached to "$ctrl".

Comment: post controller code also

Comment: controller code is added

Comment: Please, show all the relevant code. It's not clear how StuffController  is used. It's not clear where this `<form>` is. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: ok but I am extracting this from a larger app. I had a hope to be able to get a hint or something, before to have to replicate the whole thing online, which is really long, esp since I have not created the stack myself.

Comment: problem solved, it requires to be prefixed with $ctrl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validation object is now a property, not a string anymore.
So I had to replace :

```
<form name="foobar" ng-submit="$ctrl.submitThat()"  novalidate>
```

with:

```
<form name="$ctrl.foobar" ng-submit="$ctrl.submitThat()"  novalidate>
```

It is then available in the controller on the $ctrl object.

Little things keep changing with this framework, so that I can have entertaining afternoons.

Answer (score 0):

So assuming that $scope.foobar doesn't exist for some reason you could edit the method:

```
submitThat(form) {
  console.log('form:', form);
}
```

And obviously the original call needs altering:

```
<form name="foobar" onSubmit="$ctrl.submitThat(foobar)" novalidate>
```

I would recommend however, that you look into 'vm', and start naming your forms (and models) with vm; John Papa's guide which is a great starting point does indicate that any model with 'dots' isn't really a model...

Comment: Thanks but I think you are confusing. I am talking about the validation object which is normally based on the form name. This is different from the model.